# Neo4j Cypher query prepopulate some data from related node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a following SDN entity:

```
NodeEntity
public class Comment extends Commentable {

    private final static String CREATED_BY = "CREATED_BY";
    private final static String COMMENTED_ON = "COMMENTED_ON";

    @RelatedTo(type = COMMENTED_ON, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Commentable commentable;

    @RelatedTo(type = CREATED_BY, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private User author;

    private String text;
    ....
}
```

and a following Cypher query:

```
    @Override
    @Query("MATCH (c:Comment) WHERE id(c) = {commentId} RETURN c")
    Comment findOne(@Param("commentId") Long commentId);
```

As a result, this query only returns `author.id` for `User author` mapping.

How to change this query in order to prepopulate for example `author.username` also ?